# `Couldn't find User without an ID` with Friendly_ID gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I am creating User Profiles with vanity URLs that use the username. The actual profile page works well, however I have my root page as the profile page if the user is signed in. If they are redirected to root then they get the error `Couldn't find User without an ID` and shows this code as the error pointing to the @user line...

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @current_user = current_user
        @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @username = "@" + @user.username
        @posting = Posting.new
    end

end
```

Here is my routes file as well...

```
devise_for :users
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
  get "profiles/show"

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get '/edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit
  end

  authenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      root to: "profiles#show", :as => "authenticated"
    end
  end

  unauthenticated do
    devise_scope :user do
      root to: "devise/sessions#new", :as => "unauthenticated"
    end
  end

  get '/:id' => 'profiles#show', as: :profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the problem with friendly id gem. The problem is that you are redirecting to a show method without supplying id, hence `params[:id]` is nil.

You can go around this by changing your `show` method:

```
def show
  @current_user = current_user # why do you need this?
  @user = params[:id] ? User.friendly.find(params[:id]) : current_user
  @username = "@" + @user.username
  @posting = Posting.new
end
```

Comment: I didn't really need the current user. I had someone looking at it and he put that in. I have no idea why but I just left it in. Thank you! I'm going to test it. How does that work or is there a place to learn those types of work arounds?

Comment: It works! I knew it wasn't the gem. I never learned things like that yet. I'm fairly new to rails(1.5mths)

Comment: @TaylorMitchell No worries, I hated rails after my first 1.5mth. Btw. it would be probably a better idea to have a separate action like `profile` for displaying current_user. `Show` action should always be executed with an id.